# How do I convert a hex triplet to an RGB tuple and back?

Tags: python, colors

I'd like to convert a hex triplet to an RGB tuple and then convert a tuple to a hex triplet.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262100/rgb-int-to-rgb-python

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/214359/converting-hex-to-rgb-and-vice-versa#214657

Comment: For Python 3 you want the `bytes`-based answers below by @Inti - clean, fast, no imports, no installs. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51556962/507544

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use a look-up table with some slicing and shifts — all relatively fast operations — to create a couple of functions that will work unchanged in both Python 2 and 3:

```
_NUMERALS = '0123456789abcdefABCDEF'
_HEXDEC = {v: int(v, 16) for v in (x+y for x in _NUMERALS for y in _NUMERALS)}
LOWERCASE, UPPERCASE = 'x', 'X'

def rgb(triplet):
    return _HEXDEC[triplet[0:2]], _HEXDEC[triplet[2:4]], _HEXDEC[triplet[4:6]]

def triplet(rgb, lettercase=LOWERCASE):
    return format(rgb[0]<<16 | rgb[1]<<8 | rgb[2], '06'+lettercase)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('{}, {}'.format(rgb('aabbcc'), rgb('AABBCC')))
    # -> (170, 187, 204), (170, 187, 204)

    print('{}, {}'.format(triplet((170, 187, 204)),
                          triplet((170, 187, 204), UPPERCASE)))
    # -> aabbcc, AABBCC

    print('{}, {}'.format(rgb('aa0200'), rgb('AA0200')))
    # -> (170, 2, 0), (170, 2, 0)

    print('{}, {}'.format(triplet((170, 2, 0)),
                          triplet((170, 2, 0), UPPERCASE)))
    # -> aa0200, AA0200
```

Answer (score 76):

```
>>> import struct
>>> rgbstr='aabbcc'
>>> struct.unpack('BBB',rgbstr.decode('hex'))
(170, 187, 204)
```

and

```
>>> rgb = (50,100,150)
>>> struct.pack('BBB',*rgb).encode('hex')
'326496'
```

Comment: In python 3.0, replace `str.decode('hex')` with `bytes.fromhex(str)` .  For the other direction, use `binascii.hexlify` to convert back to a string after packing.

Comment: In Python 2.7 `str` is the name of a built-in type. This is also true in many earlier versions, I just don't recall offhand when it was introduced. Anyway, the point is that giving a variable that name isn't generally a good practice because it hides the type. This is still a good answer, IMHO.

Comment: Converting this to work in Python 3.x is somewhat tricky -- especially (and surprisingly) the conversion to a hex triplet in the second part.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `binascii.hexlify` yields a bytes object. You'd need to call `.decode('utf-8')` on that to get a string, right? The total command is `binascii.hexlify(struct.pack('BBB', *rgb)).decode('utf-8')`. I think `'#%02x%02x%02x' % rgb` is a lot simpler, and has the benefit of dealing with float values as well as integers.

Answer (score 26):

Trying to be *pythonic*:

```
>>> rgbstr='aabbcc'
>>> tuple(ord(c) for c in rgbstr.decode('hex'))
(170, 187, 204)
>>> tuple(map(ord, rgbstr.decode('hex'))
(170, 187, 204)
```

and

```
>>> rgb=(12,50,100)
>>> "".join(map(chr, rgb)).encode('hex')
'0c3264'
```

Comment: ```rgbstr.decode('hex')```
How it will looks like for python3?

Answer (score 22):

I found a simple way:

```
red, green, blue = bytes.fromhex("aabbcc")
```

Comment: This is the simplest solution out here, that doesn't even require importing any modules.

Comment: `bytearray.fromhex()` for python 2.7

Comment: This is not only simpler, it's also faster than using struct. More so if you return tuple instead of list.

Answer (score 11):

### with [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/)

matplotlib uses RGB tuples with values between 0 and 1:

```
from matplotlib.colors import hex2color, rgb2hex

hex_color = '#00ff00'
rgb_color = hex2color(hex_color)
hex_color_again = rgb2hex(rgb_color)
```

both `rgb_color` and `hex_color` are in a format acceptable by matplotlib.

### with [webcolors](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/webcolors/1.3)

html uses RGB tuples with values between 0 and 255.

you can convert between them with the module webcolors, using the functions `hex_to_rgb`, `rgb_to_hex`

Answer (score 10):

A very simplistic approach to convert rgb to hex

```
>>> rgb = (255, 255, 255)
>>> r, g , b = rgb
>>> hex(r)
'0xff'
>>> hex(r) + hex(g)[2:] + hex(b)[2:]
'0xffffff'
>>>
```

A simplistic approach to convert Hex to rgb

```
>>> h  = '0xffffff'
>>> h1, h2, h3 = h[0:4], '0x' + h[4:6], '0x' + h[6:8]
>>> h1, h2, h3
('0xff', '0xff', '0xff')
>>> r, g , b = int(h1, 16), int(h2, 16), int(h3, 16)
>>> r, g, b
(255, 255, 255)
```

Use a module which provides some these facility: [webcolors](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/webcolors/1.3)

```
>>> hex_to_rgb('#000080')
(0, 0, 128)
>>> rgb_to_hex((255, 255, 255))
'#ffffff'
```

Function doc:

> hex_to_rgb(hex_value)
>    Convert a hexadecimal color value to a 3-tuple of integers suitable for use in an rgb() triplet specifying that color.
>
> rgb_to_hex(rgb_triplet) : 
>    Convert a 3-tuple of integers, suitable for use in an rgb() color triplet, to a normalized hexadecimal value for that color.

Comment: note that the rgb to hex fails if any of the input values are less than 16. e.g., `rgb = (0, 255, 0)` would result in `"#0x0ff0"`

Answer (score 8):

HEX to RGB tuple

```
>>> tuple(bytes.fromhex('61559a'))
(97, 85, 154)
```

RGB tuple to HEX

```
>>> bytes((97, 85, 154)).hex()
'61559a'
```

No imports needed!

---

What is this magic?!

> Since bytes objects are sequences of integers (akin to a tuple), for a
>   bytes object b, b[0] will be an integer, while b[0:1] will be a bytes
>   object of length 1
>
> ...
>
> The representation of bytes objects uses the literal format (b'...')
>   since it is often more useful than e.g. bytes([46, 46, 46]). You can
>   always convert a bytes object into a list of integers using list(b).

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-objects

Answer (score 5):

```
def hex_to_int_color(v):
    if v[0] == '#':
        v = v[1:]
    assert(len(v) == 6)
    return int(v[:2], 16), int(v[2:4], 16), int(v[4:6], 16)

def int_to_hex_color(v):
    assert(len(v) == 3)
    return '#%02x%02x%02x' % v
```

Comment: def int_to_hex_color(v):
  assert(len(v) == 3)
  return '#%02x%02x%02x' % v

Comment: Sorry, your int_to_hex_color does not return correct results when some of the colour components have values < 16. int_to_hex_color((30,20,10)) -> '#1e14a'

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

def hex_to_int_color(v):
  return tuple(int(i,16) for i in re.match(
    r'^#?([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})([0-9a-f]{2})$', v,
    flags=re.IGNORECASE).groups())

def int_to_hex_color(v):
  return '#%02x%02x%02x' % v
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. I use it to convert color to graphviz color format in `#RGBA` format with `prefix=#`.

```
def rgba_hex( color, prefix = '0x' ):
    if len( color ) == 3:
       color = color + (255,)
    hexColor = prefix + ''.join( [ '%02x' % x for x in color ] )
    return hexColor
```

USAGE:

```
In [3]: rgba_hex( (222, 100, 34) )
Out[3]: '0xde6422ff'

In [4]: rgba_hex( (0,255,255) )
Out[4]: '0x00ffffff'

In [5]: rgba_hex( (0,255,255,0) )
Out[5]: '0x00ffff00'
```