# How can ImageMagick output hex colours instead of SRGB?

Tags: bash, imagemagick

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47982983/how-to-get-a-hex-color-code-from-a-solid-color-image-for-a-script/47983282?noredirect=1#comment82935434_47983282), someone asked how to get the average colour of an image in hexadecimal notation. After some research, I found a somewhat working solution using ImageMagick:

```
user@laptop:~$ convert rose: -scale 1x1\! -format '%[pixel:s]\n' info:-
```

The problem is that this prints `srgb(146,89,80)` instead of the desired `#925950`.

I tried reading through the documentation of [`-format`](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/escape.php), which did mention a `%[hex:]` "thing", but when substituting `%[pixel:s]` for `%[hex:s]`, I get the following error:

```
convert: unknown image property "%[hex:s]" @ warning/property.c/InterpretImageProperties/3678.
```

I also tried reading the documentation for [`FX Expressions`](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/fx.php), but I have no idea how I would go about outputting the result as hex code instead of SRGB.

Comment: A little closer but no hex numbers: `'#%[fx:round(r*256)] %[fx:round(g*256)] %[fx:round(b*256)]\n'`

Comment: I think you need to do: `declare $(convert rose: -scale 1x1\! -format "rr=%[fx:round(255*r)]\ngg=%[fx:round(255*g)]\nbb=%[fx:round(255*b)]\n" info:)` Then do: `printf "#%02x%02x%02x\n" $rr $gg $bb`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got an error most likely because your version of ImageMagick is too old. The changelog says:

```
2017-06-02 6.9.8-9 Cristy <quetzlzacatenango@image...>
Add support for 'hex:' property.
```

If that version or later use:

```
convert rose: -scale 1x1\! -format "%[hex:u]\n" info:
925950

convert rose: -scale 1x1\! -format "%[hex:s]\n" info:
925950

convert rose: -scale 1x1\! -format "%[hex:u.p{0,0}]\n" info:
925950

convert rose: -scale 1x1\! -format "#%[hex:u]\n" info:
#925950

convert rose: -scale 1x1\! -format "#%[hex:s]\n" info:
#925950

convert rose: -scale 1x1\! -format "#%[hex:u.p{0,0}]\n" info:
#925950
```

If earlier, then

```
convert rose: -scale 1x1\! txt: | tail -n +2 | sed -n 's/^.*[#]\(.*\) .*$/\1/p'
925950 

convert rose: -scale 1x1\! txt: | tail -n +2 | sed -n 's/^.*\([#].*\) .*$/\1/p'
#925950
```

It is always best to provide your ImageMagick version and platform, when asking questions about ImageMagick commands, since syntax may vary and new feature may be added or bugs fixed.

Comment: You can also shorten it: `convert rose: -scale 1x1\! txt: | grep -Eo '#[^ ]+'`

Comment: `@Cyrus`. Nice. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Append:

```
| awk -F '[(,)]' '{printf("#%x%x%x\n",$2,$3,$4)}'
```

Output:

```
#925950
```

Comment: I was hoping for an answer purely in ImageMagick, but if awk works, then that's it.