# Getting ImageMagick to output ALL colors as hex

Tags: colors, formatting, imagemagick, command-line-arguments

I want `identify -verbose myImage.jpg` to output all color values in hex format.

I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47983587/how-can-imagemagick-output-hex-colours-instead-of-srgb) but it only works for a single color; eg:

```
$ identify -verbose -format '%[hex:u]\n' myImage.jpg 
F9CBA9
```

compared to not specifying a format:

```
$ identify -verbose myImage.jpg
Image: /home/rena/img/myImage.jpg
  Format: JPEG (Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format)
  Mime type: image/jpeg
  Class: DirectClass
  [...lots more info here...]
  Background color: white
  Border color: srgb(223,223,223)
  [...]
  Version: ImageMagick 7.0.9-5 Q16 x86_64 2019-11-18 https://imagemagick.org
```

What I want is the latter output, except for properties that list a color to list it in hex, eg "#FFFFFF" and "#DFDFDF" instead of "white" and "srgb(223,223,223)".

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `txt:` protocol to write all pixel information in a text format, and pipe the results to the `cut` utility.

```
magick myImage.jpg txt:- | cut -d ' ' -f 4
```

You can also use `uniq` to remove duplicate hex-color entries.

```
magick myImage.jpg txt:- | cut -d ' ' -f 4 | uniq
```

Comment: That looks like it's listing every single pixel, which isn't what I want.