# Convert an int to a CSS colour

Tags: python, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [RGB Int to RGB - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262100/rgb-int-to-rgb-python)

Using Python I need to convert an int to a six digit hex that I can use as a background colour in CSS. Any ideas how to do that?

The int is a primary key of a model in Django.

Comment: What int is that, what does it signify? Any int? Is it something random?

Comment: Can you give an example of the int? Is it a three int tuple? e.g. `color = (255, 255, 255)`

Comment: The int is a primary key of a model in Django.

Comment: This question should not have been closed. The so-called duplicate question is about converting one `int` into 3 `ints`, while this question is about  converting one `int` into a `str`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Convert an int to a 6-digit hex:

```
In [10]: '{0:06X}'.format(16746513)
Out[10]: 'FF8811'
```

Check that the hex is equivalent to the int:

```
In [9]: int('FF8811',16)
Out[9]: 16746513
```

Comment: Brilliant that is exactly what I'm after.

Comment: Actually you should use `format(16746513, '06X')`

Answer (score 5):

IF you really just have an integer then `"#" + hex(value)` will return the appropriate code to use. However, if you have a tuple of three 0-225 integers then you need to convert the three of them to hex values, pad them if necessary and join them together. You can do this with a single string formatting operation.

```
hex = "#%02x%02x%02x" % (r, g, b)
```

The `%02x` means zero pad the number to two digits which the `x` means convert to lowercase hexidecimal. Use `X` if you want uppercase.