# pywin32: Get color by using coordinates

Tags: python, colors, pywin32

I wrote this code to make a mouse click on the x,y position 100,200 and after that I'm pressing the backspace button:

```
import win32api, win32con
import time

def click(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)

def press_back():
    win32api.keybd_event(0x08,0,0,0) #click backspace
    time.sleep(0.1)
    win32api.keybd_event(0x08,0,2,0) #release backspace

click(100,200)
press_back()
```

What I want to do now is to check if the color at 100,200 is red. How can I do this?

EDIT:
I have the solution...

```
color = win32gui.GetPixel(win32gui.GetDC(win32gui.GetActiveWindow()), 100 , 200)
```

thanks anyways

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your answer

```
color = win32gui.GetPixel(win32gui.GetDC(win32gui.GetActiveWindow()), 100 , 200)
```

you get an integer, which for someone (like me) could be not really friendly.

If you want an RGB tuple, you can check this answer: [RGB Int to RGB - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262100/rgb-int-to-rgb-python).

```
def rgbint2rgbtuple(RGBint):
    blue =  RGBint & 255
    green = (RGBint >> 8) & 255
    red =   (RGBint >> 16) & 255
    return (red, green, blue)
```

Finally, you have tho check if the color is red, that could be not so easy if you accept also similar colors, not only and simply the *pure* red (that is (255, 0, 0)).