# How to get a list of float RGBA pixels values using Pillow?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to get a list of float RGBA pixels values using Pillow python module.

So far I could only get the RGBA integer data:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("Lenna.png")
im_alpha = im.convert('RGBA')
Pixels = list(im.getdata())
```

This will get me for instance ((226, 137, 125, 255), ...)
However I don't know how to get this information in a form of floating points, for instance ((0.88627451, 0.537254902, 0.490196078, 1), ...).

How can I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262100/rgb-int-to-rgb-python

Comment: @PeteyPii How does this help me? I want the pixel info to be in the form (0.1454,0.4572,1,1), And of course I can just normalize it, but I am looking for a better way to do it using Pillow itself.

Comment: Oh, I misinterpreted your question. You should clarify exactly what you mean in the question.

Comment: I don't think PIL stores pixel values in float. Because even if you did manage to   convert your image to  `type float`, you will get the pixel values as : `255.0, 35.0, 168.0, 87.0,.....` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I was using for RGB .png:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy

# http://www.schaik.com/pngsuite/basn2c16.png
im = Image.open('basn2c16.png')
#~ data = numpy.asarray(im)
data = numpy.array(im) # same as .asarray
print("Array dimensions: %s"%(repr(data.shape)))
data = data.astype(float)
print("[20, 30]=%s"%(repr(data[20, 30])))
print(data)
data = numpy.divide(data, 255.0)
print(data)
```

Nowever, note that it depends on type of .png; for instance, see http://www.schaik.com/pngsuite/pngsuite_bas_png.html for test files, and for [`basn2c16.png`](http://www.schaik.com/pngsuite/basn2c16.png) which is "3x16 bits rgb color", the printouts are:

```
Array dimensions: (32, 32, 3)
[20, 30]=array([   8.,   90.,  156.])
[[[ 255.  255.    0.]
  [ 247.  255.    0.]
  [ 239.  255.    0.]
...
[[[ 1.          1.          0.        ]
  [ 0.96862745  1.          0.        ]
  [ 0.9372549   1.          0.        ]
  ...,
```

So, even if this is 16-bit, the values seem to span 0-255, as if for 8-bit. In this case, we need to scale the data with `numpy.divide` with 255 to get a float range 0.0-1.0 ...

However, if you use an indexed/palleted png [`basn3p08.png`](http://www.schaik.com/pngsuite/basn3p08.png), you get:

```
Array dimensions: (32, 32)
[20, 30]=120.0
[[ 165.  165.  165. ...,  254.  254.  254.]
 [   8.    8.    8. ...,  248.  248.  248.]
....
```

so now the matrix contents do not represent RGB(A) values, but instead an index in a color palette, so dividing with 255 has no meaning.

Finally, if it's an RGBA png like [`basn6a16.png`](http://www.schaik.com/pngsuite/basn6a16.png), you will get the alpha as well:

```
Array dimensions: (32, 32, 4)
[20, 30]=array([   0.,   88.,  167.,   16.])
[[[ 255.  255.    0.    0.]
  [ 247.  255.    0.    0.]
...
```

Again, even if this is 16-bit png, the values seem scaled to 255, so dividing with 255 to obtain floats makes sense.

In other words, its relatively easy to scale the matrix values with `numpy` and PIL, however, you should make sure the matrix is in the right format for that...